# What is the genjutsu called that Madara is trying to use to mind control the whole world?

Tags: naruto

What is the genjutsu called that Madara is trying to use to mind control the whole world?

He needs the ten-tails to be able to activate it.

I know it's been mentioned frequently in the series but I watch it over a very long period of time mixed with lots of other shows. The name eludes me.

Comment: Isn't this mentioned like every *n* episodes/chapter since its inception?

Comment: Been a while and now it's just episodes of being under its control. I hardly think this warrants a down-vote. It's hard remembering specific words in a non-native language.

Comment: plothole . . . 

i doubt a genjutsu reflected from moon would affect blind people or other side of earth . . .

Comment: Ya true. Maybe it just takes longer to get those folks or suppose the only land is all on the same hemisphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [Infinite Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi)

> The Infinite Tsukuyomi is a genjutsu that traps the entire world in an
> illusion, enslaving them in a dream so that their chakra may be drawn
> upon.

Telling more will be full of spoilers.